# "Plugin '0' is not loaded"

Tags: mysql, sql, plugins, upgrade

After upgading MySQL to newer version I have error when I want to connect to server:

```
 ERROR 1524 (HY000): Plugin '0' is not loaded
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a Bug in `MySQL` as [Bug #60432
Modifying mysql.user table can deny users from logging in](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=60432) . Which states that:

> If database manager accidentally (or deliberately) modifies mysql.user
>   table by adding any column in position lower (or equal) than
>   "max_user_connections", then after reloading privileges no one is
>   allowed to log in.

Workaround: Undoing the modification made in `user` table.

Comment: I did this:
 `mysql> alter table user add column xxx varchar(40) after max_connections;


mysql> flush privileges;
mysql> alter table user drop column xxx;

mysql> flush privileges;`

but didn't help

Comment: @Taz, you got it wrong. That's just a repro steps for the bug in that link. What I meant is ... whatever the changes made to your MySQL `user` table .. undone that.

Comment: I didn't made any changes to user

Comment: @Taz, No you didn't but may be while upgradation something in user table may have changed. See that bug report, it says exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Run following commands

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop

sudo mkdir -p /var/run/mysqld; sudo chown mysql /var/run/mysqld

sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

and then press enter

now your password get reset, you can change your password again

This works for me

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed a bug with MySQL and a changed user table structure. Unfortunately, if you don't know what changed, you can't change it back. Also, if you cannot login, you cannot fix anything either.

I fixed this as follows. Please be careful with these instructions as they may not work entirely for your setup and you could lose your data if this goes wrong. Don't blame me if it does!

#### 1. Back-up old data dir

Back-up your old data dir somewhere. This allows you to restore the tables at the end. To find out where your data dir is, you can try to initialise mysql. It will give you an error because the data dir already exists:

```
mysqld initialize
```

Output:

```
mysqld: Can't create directory '/usr/local/mysql/data/' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
```

Now backup your data dir somewhere:

```
cp -r /usr/local/mysql/data ~/backup-dir/
```

#### 2. Re-initialize MySQL

With your data dir safely backed up, remove it and re-initialize mysql. It will give you a new temporary password which you can change later.

```
rm -rf /usr/local/mysql/data
mysqld initialise
```

The output will give you a new password for 'root'. If you get permission errors, use sudo (not sure about the drawbacks).

Start the server using mysqld_safe to be sure it works the first time:

```
mysqld_safe
```

Optionally, change the root password by logging in to mysql and running alter table:

```
mysql -u root -p
<enter password>
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'New Password';
```

#### 3.Restore data

Stop the mysql server

```
mysqld stop
```

Copy all the backup files to the new data dir (run this for every db you need to restore):

```
cp -r ~/backup-dir/data/<dbname> /usr/local/mysql/data/
```

For MyISAM tables, this is enough. If you have InnoDB tables, you also need to copy the InnoDB table space from your backup:

```
cp ~/backup-dir/data/ibdata* /usr/local/mysql/data/
```

Then, fix permissions (look at the files already present in /usr/local/mysql/data for the right permissions, mine were 'mysql' for both user and group):

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /usr/local/mysql/data/*
```

Start the mysql server

```
mysqld start
```

All done! You should be able to login again and your tables should be back containing all data, too.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to fix this...

1. change the configuration file --my.cnf (usually in /etc/my.cnf)
2. add "skip-grant-tables" below [mysqld]
3. now you can login the mysql! backup your database and re-install mysql

I think this will completely repair the problems.
(Plugin 0 is not loaded, i found i cant backup the database then..so you need to add something in mysql.cnf)

Answer (score 0):

I restarted my MySql server and Apache web server and it worked.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31156779)