# Mysql Password Hash Gets Saved Into Plugin Column in myql.user Table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am running MySQL locally on my iMac (OS X 10.11.1), installed through Homebrew (currently it is mysql version 5.7.9). I also have Phpmyadmin installed through Homebrew (currently on version 4.5.1 since 4.5.2 is not yet available through Homebrew). Here is the problem:

When I am creating a new user (no matter whether I go through the command line or phpmyadmin) with the following syntax:

`CREATE USER 'test'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'pass';`

or with the default phpmyadmin syntax:

`CREATE USER 'test1'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password AS '***';`

the user created does show as having no password in phpmyadmin. Upon examining the mysql.user table I can see the following:

`Host | User  | Password | (...) | x509_subject | (...) | plugin      | (...)
  %   | test1 | (empty)  | (...) | [BLOB-1 B]   | (...) | (Pass Hash) | (...)`

This is obviously wrong but I cannot figure out why and how to fix this. This only just happened recently all users created earlier have been added to the table correctly where the plugin column reads `mysql_native_password` as expected and the password hash is in the password column not in the plugin one.

I have found this post which poses a similar problem: ["Plugin '0' is not loaded"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31962242/plugin-0-is-not-loaded)

However since I am still able to login with all previously created users without problems I think it is just a similar problem but not exactly the same.

Even stranger: my colleague has the exact same setup on her iMac and the same problem, while I have also the same setup on my MacBook Air which behaves correctly however… On it I can create users without problems and everything gets written into the correct columns.

Comment: [On behalf of Deven Bansod]  Have you made any changes to the 'mysql.'user' table or not ? 
May be you could check the standard columns at :
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant-table-structure.html

And if you have done some changes, then you should 'undo' those
changes since that is the most likely cause of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have checked my `mysql.user` table against the standard columns and found that they're sorted differently (which in my opinion should not be a problem) and three columns are missing: `password_last_changed`, `password_lifetime`, `account_locked`. Might this be the issue?

Also I have not directly touched the user table myself (at least not to my memory), might the continued updating of versions through Homebrew cause the issue?

Am I correct to assume that the easiest solution would be a dump of all tables (minus the mysql table) and a complete reinstall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your mysql.user table is non-standard for MySQL 5.7, you might want to update it. The recommended way is the mysql_upgrade utility, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-upgrade.html.